Google Calendar Watch: How do I get details of the event that was changed
I have an application that manages the user's calendar for them. Initially, I set this up by getting single events for the user within the next two months. (This let me not have to deal with recurring events, I just get each event seperately).
I set up watch for the user. However, the request for the watch event doesn't contain event details at all. I expected this in the request body, but the request body is empty.
How do I receive the event details for which the udpate happened:
Request headers {
  'x-real-ip': '---',
  'x-goog-resource-uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[[calendarId]]/events?alt=json',
  'x-goog-resource-state': 'exists',
  'x-goog-resource-id': '[[resourceId]]',
  'x-goog-message-number': '1015021',
  'x-goog-channel-id': '6673183088affefaa7ef3081',
  'x-goog-channel-expiration': 'Wed, 26 Jun 2024 19:27:48 GMT',
  'x-forwarded-server': '5fdoa23',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'x-forwarded-port': '443',
  'x-forwarded-host': 'webhook.loca.lt',
  'x-forwarded-for': '...ipaddress...',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-length': '0',// request body is empty, i guess
  'user-agent': 'APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)',
  host: '<server>',
  connection: 'close',
  'x-clerk-auth-status': 'signed-out',
  'x-clerk-auth-token': '',
  'x-clerk-auth-message': '',
  'x-clerk-auth-reason': 'header-missing-non-browser',
  'x-middleware-invoke': '',
  'x-invoke-path': '/api/calendars/[calendarId]/webhook',
  'x-invoke-query': '%7B%7D',
  'x-invoke-output': '/api/calendars/[calendarId]/webhook'
}
REQUEST BODY: 
(empty)
Query: 
{ calendarId: 'calendarIdInternal' }

If the request body is supposed to be empty, I have to do a full refetch for the next two months. This might become expensive for users who actively change their calendar around.
I thought of using a syncToken, but since I am using single Events, even if there is one recurring event, their events will loop forever. and I'll never actually get a sync token

From what I know, to get the details of the events that were changed, you'll need to perform a list request using Incremental sync to synchronize the events and syncToken to only get the ones that were changed. If that's not going to work for you, another method that you can try to do is use Events: list with the updatedMin parameter to retrieve events modified after a specific date and time.

Also, I would recommend that you use Events: watch with Push notifications to inform your application when a resource changes. That way, you'll receive real-time updates on when there's a change because of the notification, rather than performing periodic checks.

It seems the only way to do this is to do this is to get detail from the Events API. The watch notification request doesn't contain any information about what change. You can use a sync token and store it in your database and use that to only get changes since your last sync.
